# Python string instead of unknown module name

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module

I have made a simple code to something like this:

- It accepts a string (name) from user
- then it do some customization to the string (turn lowercase and replacing space with "_"{under score})
- then after customization, it will search for a file with same name as string
- then display the content of file. here is its code:

```
    import coder
    import time
    import calc
    
    mainfunc = ["clears", "action mode"]
    
    main_loop = "main"
    coder.clear_screen()
    while main_loop == "main":
        ask = input("BOT: You say? > ")
        mask = ask.replace(" ", "_")
        if mask == mainfunc[0]:
            print("\n" * 100)
            coder.clear_screen()
        else:
            prt = open(mask, "r")
            pr = prt.read()
            print(pr)
            prt = open(mask, "r")
            pr = prt.read()
            print(pr)
```

This is what I can with text, and I have plan to do same thing with some python modules (like instead of displaying its code, it should execute the code), which search for the module name with the string given by user! It's like unknown module to be executed with name of string.

I have tried `getattr` and others like `{}.format`, ...
but non worked. I have researched the documentation section of functions and modules, but didn't found anything to help or it was too confusing while I don't know the name of what I am searching for.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of what you're asking. What do you mean w.r.t. running code instead of displaying it?

Comment: Are you asking for the ability of a user to specify what module they want to import? This probably creates more issues than it solves; what is the application?

Comment: Yes Roganjosh, I want the user to specify what module to import! Iam making a custom system for my artificial intelligence

Comment: This would expose you to vulnerabilities. You're asking for user input to dictate what code is run. This is not advisable unless you're confident that you know how to contain this freedom. I strongly suggest you rethink the  foundations of this approach rather than us answer how this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's [`exec` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) will execute a string as raw code, which lets you do something like this:

```
module = input("Enter module to import:")
exec("import " + module)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a specific answer to your question, but of more general utility. This code (from pimoroni.com, used in their Enviro Pico W aboard series) uses a parameter 'model' to choose which one of several different modules to import, with the 'as' resulting in the imported modules adopting the same name!

```
# return the module that implements this board type
def get_board():
  if model == "indoor":
    import enviro.boards.indoor as board
  if model == "grow":
    import enviro.boards.grow as board
  if model == "weather":
    import enviro.boards.weather as board
  if model == "urban":
    import enviro.boards.urban as board
  return board
```

Comment: Please update the website address in your answer so that it directs to the actual page that this code is from. Currently, it directs to a page with items for sale and as such, your answer may be flagged as spam.